# Group by ignoring content after a phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a load of subject lines which include the phrase "sent to XXXXXXX" tacked onto the end of them.

I'm wanting to do a count of the different subject lines, but because the sent to bit is tacked onto it I can't compare them.

e.g.

```
select subject from notebookitems
```

brings back

```
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer sent to Joe Bloggs
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer sent to Benny Hill
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer sent to Hugh Dennis
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer sent to Jimmy Nail
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer sent to Bob Jones
```

whereas what I'm actually wanting to bring back is just

```
Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer
```

or even better

```
3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer
```

so I can count the distinct subjects

Comment: If this is separate information (i.e. Subject is "Mailshot 3rd Line Support / Cloud Engineer" and it is sent to "Joe Bloggs", it would make so much more sense to store just the subject in one column, and who it is sent to in another column (probably called SentTo). However, you could just use `SUBSTRING(subject, 1, CHARINDEX(' sent to ', subject) - 1)` to get everything to the left of " sent to"

Comment: @GarethD Yeah, it would make more sense to store it like that, but we're dealing with fitting information into someone else's product that we can't alter the schema of! Grumble grumble etc etc...!  I'll try the charindex though, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query should help:

```
select Left(subject,CHARINDEX(' sent to ',subject)) as Subject, 
       count(*) as Count
from notebookitems
group by Left(subject,CHARINDEX(' sent to ',subject))
```

Also if you are very sure that subject will always start with `Mailshot` and you want to remove it from final output then use `REPLACE` funciton as:

```
select Replace(Left(subject,CHARINDEX(' sent to ',subject)),'Mailshot ','') as Subject, 
       count(*) as Count
from notebookitems
group by Left(subject,CHARINDEX(' sent to ',subject))
```

Hope this helps!!